# Spring controller, return to specific area of the page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>

    <div style="height: 1200px">
    </div>

    <p id="rightHere">
      There there
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

and this controller :

```
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public String greetingForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
    return "greeting";
}
```

What I'm trying to do is return to greeting#rightHere but I can't get it work. Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Don't know the thymeleaf syntax, but make sure that the action of your form is '/greeting#rightHere'. Or use JavaScript to scroll where you want to when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution that worked for me:

```
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public String greetingForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
    return "redirect:greeting#rightHere";
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense to say "`return greeting#rightHere`". That is a hyperlink, you would be returning hyperlinks if you were creating a REST API. Not sure about if frameworks like Spring even know about what comes after the #. The # is suppose to be for the browser, that it will scroll to that element for you if it exists. Although I could be wrong I believe a Spring Controller won't know the different between a get URL request from `greeting#rightHere` and `greeting`, without accessing the underlying HTTP request object, (which most of the time you should never do) the behaviour in your app should be the same.

I would suggest testing this out, make sure you have allot of text on your page so you can notice jumping to your html element with the id=rightHere. And have a hyperlink in your app somewhere `/greeting#rightHere` and see if it works. I think it will, you shouldn't have to do anything in your Spring controller.

**Edit:** I think it is unclear what is being asked here. I assumed you meant you want that when you click on a link on your webpage `/greeting#rightHere`, you want the web-browser to navigate to the greeting page and then scroll to the html element which has an id of rightHere. And I'm telling you that SpringDoesn't know anything about what comes after the #, that the # is for the browser, and that the browser itself will look at the URL `/greeting#rightHere`, navigate to greeting, and then look for a HTML element with the id rightHere, and scroll there once the page loads.

But maybe you mean you want your controller to return a subsection of the greeting page, as in only the rightHere element, which you would do with templates or includes in JSP. But it's hard to determine what you are asking, as you don't seem to understand what I write, and mix talking about two different things, returning and jumping... Please consider re-writing your question and be concise in what you want to achieve using the correct language.

Comment: The goal is to be able to jump to that block immediately when loading the page after the controller return value. Not sure if I wasn't clear enough or if I didn't understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this:

at template (index.html):

```
<div id="index-section4">
...
<form id="addLeaduser" th:action="@{/save}" method="POST" 
th:object="${leaduser}">
 ...
 <input  type="submit" value="Apply">
 </form>
 ...
</div>
```

at the IndexController:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String saveLeaduser(@ModelAttribute("leaduser")
                                   LeaduserEntity leaduser,
                           @RequestParam(name="g-recaptcha-response")
                                   String captcha, Model model)
{
...
return "redirect:#index-section4";
}
```

There is only one template index.html, after submit the form it jumps to the form location, in this case at the bottom of the page.